# How to know what plugins are installed in my Oh My Zsh

Tags: command-line, plugins, zsh

I want to install 2 Oh My Zsh plugins, but I don't know their names. My brother had also downloaded them some years ago, but he doesn't know their names either.

How can I know what Oh My Zsh plugins are installed in my brother's `zsh`?

Comment: I find one of this plugins **:)** plugin 1: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/colorize

Comment: but i don'n know haw i can install it after read the "readme" file **:(**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suppose that you [installed Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/#install) by running the following command:

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

In this case, Oh My Zsh plugins are installed in the `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins` directory, so running the following command will return a list of your *installed* plugins:

```
ls ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins
```

To enable a plugin, just add its name (as shown from the above command) in `plugins=(...)` in your `~/.zshrc` file. From the [Oh My Zsh wiki](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Plugins):

> Enable a plugin by adding its name to the plugins array in your `.zshrc` file (found in the `$HOME` directory). For example, this enables the `rails`, `git` and `ruby` plugins, **in that order**:
>
> ```
> plugins=(rails git ruby)
> ```

You can list the *enabled* plugins with:

```
echo $plugins
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answer

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

There's another way of listing and enabling/disabling installed plugins using the `omz` command.

- To **list installed plugins** you can run:

  ```
  omz plugin list
  ```
- To **enable a plugin** you can run:

  ```
  omz plugin enable <plugin>
  ```

  where `<plugin>` is the name of the plugin you wish to enable. For example, to enable the `common-aliases` plugin, you would run:

  ```
  omz plugin enable common-aliases
  ```
- To **disable a plugin** you can run:

  ```
  omz plugin disable <plugin>
  ```

  For example, to disable the `common-aliases` plugin, you would run:

  ```
  omz plugin disable common-aliases
  ```
- The `omz` command is pretty handy and can also be used to **obtain information about a plugin**:

  ```
  omz plugin info <plugin>
  ```

  For example, running `omz plugin info ufw` returns information about the `ufw` plugin:

  ````
  # UFW plugin

  This plugin adds completion for managing everybody's favorite Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW),
  a simple interface for managing iptables. Learn more about [`UFW`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall).

  To use it, add ufw to the plugins array of your zshrc file:
  ```
  plugins=(... ufw)
  ```

  Some of the commands include:

  * `allow <port>/<optional: protocol>` add an allow rule 
  * `default` set default policy
  * `delete <port>/<optional: protocol>` delete RULE
  * `deny <port>/<optional: protocol>` add deny rule
  * `disable` disables the firewall
  * `enable` enables the firewall`
  ````

For more information about `omz`'s usage you can run:

```
omz --help
```